# Using lookhead/lookaround to find all digits in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

This is the sentence ('Line#:' is not part of the sentence):

```
Line1: Number 1 is 100, number 2 is 4.567
Line2: Number 11 is 101, number 21 is 44.567
Line3: Number 111 is 102, number 211 is 444.567
```

I want to construct a regex in python to return all the digits for each each line:

```
Line 1 returns: [1, 100, 2, 4.567]
Line 2 returns: [11, 101, 21, 44.567]
Line 3 returns: [111, 102, 211, 444.567]
```

The regex expression I come up with:

```
(?<=Number )\d*
```

only returns: [1], [11],[111]

and the following won't return anything:

```
(?<=Number )\d*(?<= is )\d*(?<=, number )\d*(?<= is )\d*
```

Please help.

Comment: Are the lines in good form? Do you expect any `123.456.789` or end of sentence numbers `is 4.5.`?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s="Number 1 is 100, number 2 is 4.567"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\b[\d\.]+\b',s)
['1', '100', '2', '4.567']
```

and for convert to `int` and `float` :

```
>>> try :
...  map(int,re.findall(r'[\d\.]+',s))
... except:
...  map(float,re.findall(r'[\d\.]+',s))
... 
[1.0, 100.0, 2.0, 4.567]
```

Comment: try `s = "Number 111 is 102, number12 211 is 444.567"`

Answer (score 1):

Your lookbehind `(?<=Number )\d*` works for the first number, but because regex matching is case-sensitive by default, the digits following the word `"number"` are not matched. To change this behavior, you can add the `re.I` flag to ignore the case:

```
>>> s = "Number 1 is 100, number 2 is 4.567"
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=Number )\d+", s, re.I)
['1', '2']
```

If you want to use lookbehind assertions for the whole task you could do something like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=Number )\d+|(?<=Is )[\d\.]+", s, re.I)
['1', '100', '2', '4.567']
```

The pipe `|` means "or", so we're matching a number preceded by `"Number "`, *or* a number preceded by `"Is "` (ignoring the case of the letters).

An important point is that lookbehind requires a fixed-width assertions: we can't "simplify" the expressions to one lookbehind assertion with something like `(?<=Number |Is )` because the two words are of different lengths. Expressions involving syntax like `+` or `*` can't be used in lookbehinds for the same reason.